# How to select words with punctuation and exclude periods from abbreviations?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following Ruby Regex that selects punctuation and excludes periods that are part of numbers:

```
/\p{L}+|(?!\.\d)[[:punct:]]/

The profit was 5.2 thousand dollars.

=> The profit was thousand dollars.
```

I have a regex that can select abbreviations (U.S.A) for example:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]\.){2,}
```

`The U.S.A. is located in North America`.

```
=> U.S.A.
```

I would like to use the ideas behind these regexes so that I can select all of the words and punctuation in a sentence except for any periods in any abbreviation as:

```
The U.S.A. is located in North America!

=> The USA is located in North America!
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: The example does not look quite to the point, it looks as if all you want is to find abbreviations with your regex and remove dots from the matches. Or are you planning to get an array of the matches and have dots removed from the array items that are abbreviations?

Comment: I am planning on getting all of the text and punctuation and put them into an array excluding any punctuation('.') that are from abbreviations. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, but I think it should be done in 2 steps. You cannot match discontinous parts of text with one matching iteration. See https://ideone.com/ousKNY

Comment: Wiktor I like your solution. Could you post it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "The U.S.A. have 50.1415 states approx and are located in North America!"
str.gsub(/(?<!\p{L}\p{L})\P{L}*\.[^\p{L}\s]*/, '').squeeze
#⇒ "The USA have states aprox and are located in North America!"
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the result split up into an array as follows: ["The", "USA", "have", "states", "aprox", "and", "are", "located", "in", "North", "America", "!"] and also match the period in an abbreviation like Dr.

Comment: `str.gsub(/(?<!\p{Lower}\p{L})\P{L}*\.[^\p{L}\s]*/, '').split` please note, that you’ll get new and new and new conditions needed to be included into the regexp constantly. The proper way would be to go with `lex`/`yacc`.

Comment: Your answer works very well for my current application. I will follow your advice and look into lex/yacc as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be done in 2 steps because you cannot match discontinuous parts of text with one matching iteration.

Use

```
s = 'The U.S.A. is located in North America!'
s = s.gsub(/\b(?:\p{L}\.){2,}/) { $~[0].gsub(".", "")  }
puts s.scan(/\p{L}+|(?!\.\d)[[:punct:]]/)
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/ousKNY)

The first step is to run a `gsub` with the `\b(?:\p{L}\.){2,}` pattern (I added a word boundary to make sure the pattern only matches 1 letter chunks). Within the block, the match value is stripped from dots using a literal text replacement.

The second step is running your first regex within a `scan` to collect the chunks you need.

Comment: This works. I was also trying out mudasobwa's answer as it accomplishes the same thing on one line.

Comment: Wiktor is there a way to get your regex to detect the period in Dr.

Comment: This might be a case when you want to handle all abbreviations in one step. [This paragraph splitting Ruby library](https://github.com/apohllo/srx-english/blob/master/lib/srx/english/sentence_splitter.rb) contains some nice regexps. See [this one to handle a lot of abbreviations](http://rubular.com/r/F9ytXwKb82).

Answer (score 0):

I think using regex alone will be difficult, I'll be glad to be corrected with a working solution.

**My solution:**
Parse the code that you don't want (the abbreviations) using your second regex first, and then use the first regex (selects words and punctuations). This will effectively hide the abbreviations for processing when you run your first regex.

I have a similar requirement for a project.  The key thing is to use the [partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-partition) method, loop through the regex's (2 in your case) and make sure you don't use the same regex to the string that was `"captured"` by the previous regex in the loop.

You may use this class from github: [SourceParser](https://github.com/roycetech/Anki-Tools/blob/master/anki_card_maker/lib/source_parser.rb) and use it like this:

```
parser = SourceParser.new
parser.regexter('abbrs', /(?:[a-zA-Z]\.){2,}/) # return matched as is
parser.regexter(
    'first regex', 
    /\p{L}+|(?!\.\d)[[:punct:]]/, 
    lambda do |token, regexp|
        "(#{token})"
    end
)
parser.parse("The U.S.A. is located in North America")
# => (The) U.S.A. (is) (located) (in) (North) (America)
```