# How to NOT select periods that follow a ')' with regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following ruby regex that I use to ignore periods '.' that follow abbreviations that contain periods:

```
ex: U.S.A. 

(?<!\p{Lower}\p{L})\P{L}*\.[^\p{L}\s]*

=>''
```

However, it is selecting the periods that follow brackets as follows:

```
(supervised data).

=>.
```

I would like to know how I can alter this regex expression to not select the  periods '.' but still select the periods after abbreviations such as U.S.A. and Dr.

Comment: Try `/(?<!\p{L}{2}|\))\./` or even `/(?<!\p{L}{2}|\p{P})\./`.

Comment: Wiktor your regex works to not select the '.' after a bracket, however now its not selecting the period after Mr. or Mrs. or Dr. Any way to add this to it?

Comment: (?:[^\.|\(|\)])([\.]+) . How about this ?

Comment: Let me remind you: as I have already told in the comments to the previous question, you will encounter more and more and more  and more and more  and more and more  and more and more  and more and more  and more and more  and more and more  and more and more  and more and more  and more and more  and more and more  and more and more corner cases to bother the community with them. Yes, I have downvoted the question.

Comment: I appreciate what you say and I understand your down vote.  I'm still learning a lot and thought I could get some guidance on this one point as I thought it was an easy fix to something that has been escaping me. I have looked into lex/yacc and I think its beyond me for the moment.

Comment: Wiktor could you add your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: But you said it did not work. Does it? Do you mean this one - `/(?<!\p{Lower}\p{L}|\))\./` - works? But then a `.` after `Mrs`  does not get matched. Abbreviations are a bit too difficult to deal with by a single short generic pattern.

Comment: It does not catch the period after Dr. or Mrs. but I'm willing to compromise as I have more cases where the ). situation arises

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I can answer it, it is too broad/unclear a question for me. Also, see [my comment in your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736317/how-to-select-words-with-punctuation-and-exclude-periods-from-abbreviations#comment70708612_41737395) for some hints on how to deal with abbreviations. It would also be a good idea to use some NLP package to handle abbreviations properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a letter to precede the period. Make a letter to precede a period then.

```
(?<!\p{Lower})\P{L}+\.[^\p{L}\s]*
```